# What is the default duration that a cached HTTP response is fresh?

Tags: http, caching

[Cache-control mechanisms](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.1.3) "typically override the default caching algorithms." That means we can control the expiration of cached responses, after which the saved response is stale. I.e. we can [modify the basic expiration mechanism](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3). E.g.

`Cache-control: s-maxage=3600, must-revalidate, max-age=0`

What is the "default" duration, though, within which the "caching algorithms" consider a saved response to be fresh? In other words, what, if any, are the default max-age or Expires values?

The w3 indicates the use of [heuristic expiration](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.2) when "servers do not ... provide explicit expiration times" but "does not provide specific algorithms." The implication is that the cache provider (e.g. FireFox, Internet Explorer, Chrome) has discretion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox takes the number of seconds since the `Last-Modified` date, divides that by 10, and then adds the result to current timestamp (e.g. if the `Last-Modified` date is exactly 10 days ago, then the response will be cached for exactly 1 day).

If no `Last-Modified` header is sent, then it does not cache the response by default.